# Conditions in wihch ladies not allowed to recite Quran Pak

Tags: hadith, islamic-basis, verses

How many conditions are  there in which ladies are not allowed to recite Quran Pak in the light of hadith and any verse about it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "qur'an pak"?

Comment: Quran Pak mean the holy Quran. The book of Muslims

Answer (score -1):

If women are not in the condition of Janabat or hamwari (Periods) or during birth time of any baby or when starting of bleeding then Islam does not allow to read the Quran

Comment: I hope that you meant the opposite: As the commonly known rule is that women in menses etc. are not allowed to read the Qur'an! This post could profit from some elaboration.

Comment: I want answer in the light hadith or verse about this topic @shahid